# 2 different configuration on EHCache in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: caching, playframework, playframework-2.3

In Play >=2.4 we have `play.cache.bindCaches` param to configure several defferent configs of Cache (EHCache).

How to do such thing in Play 2.3?

I need 2 configuration: on for in-memory only caching and one with disk presistency (cache that survives app restart). 
As I see it's not possible. So how should I do 2 caches?

P.S. I cant use only one default cache (with disk persistency) because of `java.io.NotSerializableException: play.mvc.Results$Status` in some cases...

Comment: I don't think that is possible in Play before 2.4, if you want to use the Cache api's. But you can probably just create the EHCache instances by yourself (see the [Cache.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/scala/play/api/cache/Cache.scala) source).

Comment: Yep. I followed the same idea.
`CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create(configUrl);`
`cache = cacheManager.getCache("diskStoredCache");`
As EHCache documentation says `cacheManager`will be the same instance as Play's `CacheManager` in case of the same `configUrl`.